# Remove an LI element from OL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the following code works to remove the first child in an `<ol>` but what would the code be if I wanted to specify the element by its order in the array? e.g. my OL has 5 LI elements and I want to delete the third one [2].

```js
jQuery("#words li:first-child").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="words">
<li>hi</li>
<li>bye</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **jQuery** `:nth-child()` or `:eq()` Selector for performing your job.

> **:nth-child() Selector**
>
> index: The index of each child to match,
>   starting with 1, the string even or odd, or an equation ( eg.
>   :nth-child(even), :nth-child(4n) )
>
> **:eq() Selector**
>
> index: Zero-based index of the element to match.

For example -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeChild(index) {
    // :nth-child() Selector
    // index: The index of each child to match, starting with 1.
    $('ol li:nth-child(' + index + ')').remove(); 

    // Using :eq() Selector
    // index: Zero-based index of the element to match.
    $('ol li:eq(' + index + ')').remove(); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with `$('#words li:eq(0)').remove();` and that did the trick :-)

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery("#words li:nth-child(2)").remove();//note it starts at 1
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="words">
<li>hi</li>
<li>bye</li>
</ol>
```

You can use [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

> Description: Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr">
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function click_remove(int){
                $('#words li').eq(int).remove();
                var a = $('button').length - 1;
                $('button').eq(a).remove();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol id="words">
        <li>hi</li>
        <li>bye</li>
        </ol>
        <button onclick="click_remove(0);">romove 1</button>
        <button onclick="click_remove(1);">romove 2</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `li:eq(1)` selector.